# WebApps Blog : Good Idea or not so Good Idea

Tags: discussion, blog

With the mention on [Blog.Stackoverflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) site, how possible would it be to get users interested in writing posts for a web applications blog ? Would *you* want this ?

There is currently a [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs) open for anyone interested to know more.

A couple questions/ideas from the guidelines,

**The scope and purpose of the blog.**
*Is the blog about the site? Is it about the site’s topic?*

- As mentioned by @Eight in the comments, writing posts about everyday tips and tricks using apps.
- Write about top content on the site, example [QotW: If a password is compromised, are any similar ones?](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/27/qotw-if-a-password-is-compromised-are-any-similar-ones/)
- Interesting stories/mishaps using apps, example [This Hacked Gmail Account](http://www.multitasked.net/2011/jun/27/hacked-gmail-google-account/)
- Review new web applications
- Keep up to date news about highly used applications (Facebook, Gmail, Twitter, Dropbox etc)
- Similar to [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/) but for web applications
- Similar to [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com) but without the snark and shallow depth

**Recruit contributors.**
Who will write entries for the blog?

I don't think it matters how much reputation you have, if you are interested in blogging ... give it a go! As long as you are dedicated to the task

**Schedule**
I think Wednesday would be the best time to have it, if no one has an issue with that.

Other StackExchange sites discussing

- [The Super User blog is looking for writers!](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2278/the-super-user-blog-is-looking-for-writers)
- [Programmers: Any chance of a Programmers Community Blog?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/any-chance-of-a-programmers-community-blog)
- [Bicycles: Should we have an associated blog?](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/should-we-have-an-associated-blog)

Comment: Kind of like what Lifehacker would blog about?

Comment: Yup, that could work. Could also talk about new upcoming apps. Pretty much open to any ideas right now, once users are interested.

Comment: I totally support it, with the caveat that the webapps community is rather diffuse -- that is, the site gets solid traffic and Q&A, but it is weighted heavily towards low-rep users. Do make sure you have enough avid users interested in blogging (or at least one or two extremely dedicated users).

Comment: p.s. I nominate @eight if only because my mind reels at the type of blog post he would generate.. it'd be.. Lovecraft meets Markov :)

Comment: Isn't the point of the blog to drive traffic *up*? @jef

Comment: Maybe we can get @senseful to come back and write up some posts similar to the site http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/

Answer (score 1):

We could recycle all those "questions" polling users about what web apps does this or that and have a bi-weekly (every other week) series to make some use out of those closed/closing/deleted questions.

Question of the Week - Not a fan of that. Just blog as it comes instead of pushing to have something there. With all that could be mined from the questions so far, you could ride on a wave of it for a while if you stretch it out.

Start with a post a week. Let's not burn out too quick with two or three a week. That way lies a cavernous hole of dustballs.

Comment: `Start with a post a week` -> That's the key. I told the SU folks not to push out posts too fast - and it was brushed aside. Now everyone's busy and posts come slower than a trickle