# Get Involved! WebApps Blog : Contributors

Tags: discussion, blog

In reference to [WebApps Blog : Good Idea or not so Good Idea](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/838/webapps-blog-good-idea-or-not-so-good-idea) I am going to go with the assumption that it *could* be a <s>good</s> <s>great</s> *awesome* idea and will be using this post just to see who is interested in helping out. This does not necessarily mean you have to write a post but it would great if you could help in the review of the content.

To show your participation simply put your username as an answer below and list ways in which you would be interested in helping.

Questions? Leave a comment below.

Comment: Looks like not many people are going to be willing to help but, maybe once we get it going some others will chip in?

Comment: @Fogest Currently there would need to be a few blog post drafts and a sample schedule to get the ball rolling http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/

Comment: Where do we submit these post drafts? And is there a certain length the blog posts should be over or what?

Comment: @Fogest You can try something in this format for now http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/question-ideas-for-a-hypothetical-blog and I can always ask the SE Team after collecting a 10-20 ideas. The drafts I guess don't have to be full the post just a general idea of what the post is going to be about. A few of us were thinking of pushing for this type of content and schedule http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/838/webapps-blog-good-idea-or-not-so-good-idea

Comment: @Fogest I've bugged the SE Team about it once before so maybe one more person to write posts might be what is needed to have a second go at it

Comment: @pnuts same question. Are you going to through all of this meta digging up dead questions?

Comment: Get in the way of what clutter? Clutter for whom? Unless you poke an old meta question it's not really going to surface, so I don't know where this cleanup effort comes from. Please clarify what is the problem you are seeing that needs you to do this.

Right now the only activity I am seeing in this meta is due to your mass editing of posts. The active list has now a large set of bumped edited posts :/

Answer (score 3):

I would be happy to help by reviewing and copyediting.

Answer (score 3):

I'm definitely interested. I'd be happy to write on the blog, and do reviewing. I have a lot of tips and tricks I could share but don't know where to share them.