# Blogging is not good, it's Awesome

Tags: discussion, blog

Blogging is not just a good thing, it is an excellent way for us to actually expand our traffic and Make the Internet a better place.

Now, we are currently trying to get a WebApps blog created for us (on [BlogOverflow](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/)), and we want *you* to be part of it. Unlike [previous discussions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/838/webapps-blog-good-idea-or-not-so-good-idea), we are re-defining how the blog will function for our community.

### Purpose

As clearly defined at the top, we are aiming to reach these goals with this new blog:

- Expand our traffic
- Make the Internet a better place

This blog will serve as a supporting role for our main site and is *not intended* to drain the audience of this site. Our current [social media page(s)](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/content-on-social-media-platforms) will also be supporting this new blog.

### Scope

I am proposing to have the following types of topics:

- Popular (and answered) questions on the site
- Reviews of new applications
- News of popular web applications

We are *not* [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com) or any other technology news site. We are mainly trying to keep our scope to mainly based on the questions on this site.

### Schedule

Based on comments and being a blogger myself, I would suggest that we have:

- A minimum of two posts per month
- A maximum of two posts a week (to avoid spamming our readers too much information)

Even the [StackExchange blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com) isn't updated *that* frequently. There will be no fixed date on the publication day, but the general workflow will be:

Have idea for post/Write post → Undergo review for accuracy, grammar and the like → Publish on suitable day (at least three days apart)

### Contributors

Everyone! Everyone on the site <s>must</s> should contribute at least once in a while. :D

We can have an editorial team to review and serve as "backup bloggers". This would most likely consist of rather active members of the community.

On board so far

- <s>Hydra</s>
- Jacob Jan Tuinstra
- Fogest
- Dynamic
- phwd

### Other stuff

The underlying software is [Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.org) and contains some features that are suitable for collaboration of posts. If you want to write a post, just actually begin writing on your dashboard, but do not publish it immediately. Someone from the editorial team will review, make amendments and publish on a more suitable date.

**Now**:

- Comment/Edit this question if you want to propose some small changes
- Write a new answer if you want to have a different proposal

Comment: +1 Hydra (within 5 seconds after you posted)

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Took me about three hours to draft this (was distracted midway too)

Comment: How do you get involved?

Comment: Just indicate your interest first. Once we have the blog up, you can just start writing articles on the blog itself :)

Comment: In that case, I'm interested :)

Comment: The software is from wordpress.org, not wordpress.com.

Comment: @toscho Yes, it is from wordpress.org.

Comment: @Hydra I mention it because the link goes to .com. :)

Comment: @toscho Oh, didn't see that! Thanks for that report! :D

Comment: So a note for now - this is being setup over the next couple of days. Since you've personally dropped from main support here, I'm going to tentatively appoint phwd as the admin for the blog since he's been the one prodding me 'bout this primarily. Once the whole thing is setup, though, he can distribute permissions as y'all see fit betwixt yourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too late now. The [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291741/we-will-no-longer-be-hosting-blog-overflow):

> We will no longer be hosting Blog Overflow up vote 191 down vote
>   favorite 21
>
> We are discontinuing Blog Overflow as a service on this network. Not
>   only does this mean that no new blogs will be created, but it will
>   also mean that all extant blogs are becoming functionally shut down.
>
> The reasoning is three-fold in basic:
>
> ```
> The vast majority of blogs aren't really active. This is what led to the original decision three years ago to stop creating new blogs,
> ```
>
> and that lack of activity has only since increased - at the time this
>   evaluation was started, only the SciFi blog was remotely active.
>   Again, this has a lot more to do with us having created a platform and
>   providing no proper support for people to use it.
>
> ```
> WordPress is meaty to sustain self-hosted, and there are only 3 things that were actively hosted on it: the company blog (long since
> ```
>
> moved off of that instance though), the moderator newsletter (we're
>   looking at something that can be directly a part of the Stack Exchange
>   system for this), and the site blogs make up the majority of it. Given
>   the lack of activity as mentioned, it's since become infeasible for
>   maintaining the WordPress instance for what isn't all that much
>   activity.
>
> ```
> Blogs can work with us while being external to us. We tried an internal solution because of the idea of integration with our rep and
> ```
>
> userbase seemed useful, but we never pursued that beyond a nominal
>   minimum and improving the system has never gotten to fit on our road
>   map. Meanwhile, Worldbuilding built a blog of their own on Medium,
>   which has been very productive. And so we've come to realize that this
>   kind of approach, with us supporting the endeavor rather than hosting
>   it, was going to put the hands of control to those who actually were
>   working on the system.
>
> As such, we have opted to discontinue blogs. That thus led the
>   question of what to do with the extant blogs. We reached out to the
>   communities of all the sites that had blogs, and asked them what they
>   wanted to do. We came up with 3 general solutions.
>
> The blog contains posts that wish to be retained, but no further
>   contributions will be made. Instead of hosting these on a separate
>   WordPress instance, these posts will instead be moved to a series of
>   static pages directly on our network. There will be some modifications
>   to things like the "About" pages, explaining that these are
>   functionally archives as opposed to ongoing blogs. The process for
>   setting these into static will be beginning shortly after this
>   announcement is posted on Meta. The following sites partook in this
>   option:
>
> ```
> Arqade
> Ask Different
> Aviation
> Bicycles
> Christianity
> Cross Validated
> DBA
> DIY
> English Language & Usage
> GIS
> Islam
> Mathematica
> Mathematics
> Photography
> Seasoned Advice
> Software Engineering
> Super User
> Theoretical Computer Science
> ```
>
> The blog wishes to be continued, at which point we will coordinate
>   with the community in the creation of an off-site blog. The community
>   would create and run this blog, similar to Worldbuilding's Universe
>   Factory. We in turn would provide the contents of the old articles
>   from the original blog, and provide a means to redirect traffic to the
>   old articles to instead correspond to the articles on the new
>   community-run blogs. The following sites elected to go this route:
>
> ```
> Information Security
> Science Fiction & Fantasy
> TeX - LaTeX
> ```
>
> The blog is empty or the community does not wish to preserve the
>   content, at which point the blog will be simply obliterated off the
>   face of the Internet, or would be if such a thing were possible. These
>   sites have opted for this path.
>
> ```
> Physical Fitness
> Web Applications
> ```
>
> Blogs were an interesting experiment. The idea was one we wanted to
>   work, but it was not one that we put in the effort we needed to make
>   it work. Good has come out of this project though. We've had many nice
>   articles written across many sites in this process, and we'll be happy
>   to continue hosting these articles for readers in the future. I'd like
>   to thank all of the users who had partaken in the blog process in one
>   fashion or another. This isn't the end we were expecting six years ago
>   when we started. And though this journey has officially come to a
>   close, it was a journey that had a lot of good times during it – a
>   journey worth travelling.