# What happened to our blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

Hey Web Applications community! Remember me, Hydra, from a few months back? I left Web Applications already and was hoping to let the community take over the management of the new blog that I [managed to push for](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/blogging-is-not-good-its-awesome). Real life commitments and Wiki-related work prevented me from properly contributing to the site, and I had to announce my resignation to handle those problems.

It has been a few months since I left, and was heavily anticipating the publication of our very first post. Looks like I have waited in vain, but what exactly happened? Was it because there was no one bold enough to draft up one for the blog? Did our idea for a blog just got abandoned overnight after I left?

If the answer to my second question above is "Yes", I would be more than glad to come back and help out in writing the first post for the blog. After all, I used to be part of the community once! So, where shall I begin?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10948830#10948830

Comment: Oh okay, that's good that a draft has already been created. Do speed up the process so that the blog can be more regularly updated and be considered a blog that people anticipate reading.

Comment: I'm not very into writing blog posts, but I would like to have a good reference/idea on how to start one. Be my guest !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally we should banking (posts ready to go) at least a half dozen, maybe a full dozen, so that we can start scheduling them out to roll on a regular basis.

We do have a draft sitting in there, but it's only one. We shouldn't hit publish on that one and then wait around for weeks for the next. That wouldn't look so good.

So right now it looks like we're just building up some content.

Answer (score 4):

[Stack Exchange shut down Blog Overflow back in March, 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291741).

So, "what happened" is it's dead and buried.